# Certain strings that should be found by a working Regex are missed, and I need help identifying why

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a set of strings, which I cycle through, checking those against the following set of regex, to try and separate the first small section from the rest of the string. The regex works in almost all cases, but unfortunately I have no idea why it fails occasionally.  I’ve been using Pattern Matcher to print out the string, if the pattern is found.

Two example working strings:

```
98. SORGHUM Moench - Millets Annuals or rhizomatous perennials; inflorescence …
99. MISCANTHUS Andersson - Silver-grasses Rhizomatous perennials; inflorescence …
```

Two example failed strings:

```
100. ZEA L. - Maize Annuals; male and female inflorescences separate, the …
26. POA L. (Parodiochloa C.E. Hubb.) - Meadow-grasses Annuals or perennials with or without stolons or rhizomes; sheaths overlapping or some …
```

Regex’s used so far:

```
Pattern endOfGenus = Pattern.compile("(?<=(^\\d+\\. " + genusNames[l].toUpperCase() + "))");
Pattern endOfGenusTwo = Pattern.compile("(?<=(^\\d+" + genusNames[l].toUpperCase() + "))");
Pattern endOfGenusThree = Pattern.compile("(?<=(\\d+\\. " + genusNames[l] + "))");
Pattern endOfGenusFour = Pattern.compile("(?<=(\\d+" + genusNames[l] + "))");
Pattern endOfGenusFive = Pattern.compile("(?<=(\\. " + genusNames[l] + "))");
```

The first of these is the one thats producing the reliable results so far.

Example Code

```
Pattern endOfGenus = Pattern.compile("(?<=(^\\d+\\. " + genusNames[l].toUpperCase() + "))");
Matcher endOfGenusFinder = endOfGenus.matcher(descriptionPartBits[b]);
if (endOfGenusFinder.find()) {
    System.out.print(descriptionPartBits[b] + ":- ");
    System.out.print(genusNames[l] + "\n");
    String[] genusNameBits = descriptionPartBits[b].split("(?<=(^\\d+\\. " + genusNames[l].toUpperCase() + "))"); 
}
```

Desired Output. This is what is produced by strings that work. Strings that don't work simply don't appear in the output:

```
98. SORGHUM Moench - Millets Annuals or rhizomatous perennials:- Sorghum
99. MISCANTHUS Andersson - Silver-grasses Rhizomatous perennials:- Miscanthus
```

Comment: And what's your current output? What counts as "the first small section" exactly?

Comment: I don't understand if what you posted here is the output or the input

Comment: Your examples and output don't match.  How did the `; inflorescence` dissapear from the end?  Are you splitting your input to create `descriptionPartBits` somewhere else?

Comment: Is it possible for you to put the current code that takes the input all the way to the output you are currently getting? I'm asking this so that someone can run the code against the inputs you mentioned and see how the outputs are turning out and find the appropriate solution. That said, your question might be too localized.

Comment: @Thomas The example strings are split into the array descriptionPartBits on ';', then each part of the string array is checked against the regex.

Comment: @JonSkeet The current output is whats seen in desired output. The issue is that out of the set of strings being fed into the code, a seemingly random subset of them are failing when they should work.

Comment: @ColOfAbRix The input is the working or failed strings, the output is whats found in desired output.

Comment: @Jerry I'll update with what I can

Comment: @Bobandirus: If one of them is failing, then the desired output *isn't* the same as the current output, surely. You should find an example which doesn't work, and tell us what it *should* do. It's very hard to help without concrete information.

Comment: @JonSkeet The desired output is produced from strings that work with the code. If a string that doesn't work goes through the code, there is simply no output, as if strings are being ignored. I'll post more info (like full code) soon, there's been a minor issue which will be resolved soon.

Comment: The given input strings match your regex(assuming that Zea and Poa are in your list of genus names).  Your issue is probably elsewhere.  Also, it's hard to tell from your response if things not being printed is a bug or a feature(being deliberately filtered)

Comment: @Thomas The things not being printed is a bug. Both Zea and Poa are in the list of Genus names, but both don't get printed.

Comment: Right, so it looks like you could very easily write a short but complete program which demonstrates that - input (one correctly rejected, one incorrectly rejected, one correctly passed) with expected output (two lines) and actual output (one line).

Answer (score 1):

From [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> Lookahead and lookbehind, collectively called "lookaround", are
>   zero-length assertions just like the start and end of line, and start
>   and end of word anchors explained earlier in this tutorial.

Lookahead and lookbehind only return true or false. 
So I changed your code example:

```
    Pattern endOfGenus = Pattern.compile("(?<=(^\\d+\\. ZEA L))(.+)$");
//        Matcher matcher = endOfGenus.matcher("98. SORGHUM Moench - Millets Annuals or rhizomatous perennials; inflorescence …");
        Matcher matcher = endOfGenus.matcher("100. ZEA L. - Maize Annuals; male and female inflorescences separate, the …");
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String group1 = matcher.group(1);
            String group2 = matcher.group(2);
            System.out.println("group1=" + group1);
            System.out.println("group2=" + group2);
        }
```

Group 1 is matched by `(^\\d+\\. ZEA L)`. Group 2 is matched by `(.+)`.

Comment: The issue is that there are a load of strings being fed into the code, and if the code works, potentially many, many more. Hence I'm trying to work out why this isn't working.